# RAM getting crashed in google colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I am working on the image dataset for machine learning / deep learning techniques. Currently, my image data size is 20 GB. And google colab provides 25GB RAM at maximum. Therefore, google colab is crashing every time. Please note that I need to apply dimension reduction techniques like PCA which required all the data to be present in RAM at a time. Otherwise I could have thought of breaking the training data into smaller pieces.

How can I get more RAM or any other technique to handle this issue? Can anyone help?

Comment: did you try the approach I mentioned below in the answers?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can download the data to your local and use `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` shown in [this example](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/community/en/flowers_tf_lite.ipynb).

Update `base_dir` in the example according to path of the local folder. What `ImageDataGenerator` does is, it loads only few images (you can set the number, called `batch_size`) at a time and process them. Please check the example for more details.